# No endpoint found Kaa GPIO demo

Tags: android, ubuntu, gpio, kaa

First, my scenario is:

**1-** I use Sandbox v0.9.0; and Ubuntu 14.04.

**2-** Download GPIO demo code from Sanbox.

**3-** Install GPIO demo for Android.

**4-** I flashing application on the NodeMcu development board with ESP8266 WiFi module with a CP2102 converter.

All above step is OK.

But, My problem is:

**1-** When I open the GPIO control app on the Android when I press + button and enter the token (esp8266); But not any endpoint found.

**2-** I want to Know I need set Wi-Fi SSID and password for ESP8266 when I run build.sh deploy command?!

Because by default ESP8266 just have a name.

**3-** I try with both option (set ESP8266 Wi-Fi SSID and pass, and my Wi-Fi SSID and password), but not found endpoint on the GPIO control app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

**Q:** When I open the GPIO control app on the Android when I press + button and enter the token (esp8266); But not any endpoint found.

**A:** Because we need "Trustful" option, before flashing the application.

**Follow the below steps:**

Admin panel **>** Applications **>** GPIO control slave **>** Credential service **>** Trustful **>** Saved.

This solution works well.